# Allow geolocation across browsers/devices for the same user only once, is that possible? Instead of requiring permission separately

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a question regarding allowing geolocation by the user that is non-trivial for our app.
Is there 'some' way to have the user allow geolocation on different browsers / devices in a single shot?

The situation is that we have an app concept that depends on geolocation (hence no other content will be shown as long as the user didn't confirm their location - or alternatively selected a city if they don't wish to share), but on different devices (laptop, smartphone, tablet) the user will need to confirm their geolocation every single time on different devices / browser instances as if it were the first time.

I haven't actually found information on the internet, but it seems like a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there 'some' way to have the user allow geolocation on different browsers / devices in a single shot?

No.

Comment: Ok. Then ask on every device in the webapp will be the way to go. In terms of user experience it isn't ideal though, but if there is no other way I will do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Every browser handles its permissions and geolocation in its own way. You cannot allow say geolocation permission on Safari from Chrome.

You should serve your application as a mobile app to solve your problem.